# List of Figures header not correctly modified by markboth

Tags: table-of-contents, fancyhdr

I use the `markboth` command to modify the header of the list of figures as shown in the code below. I want the header to display "List of Figures" on the bind side of the page (I use double sided pages). My list of figures is 3 pages long, the first page has no header (as wanted), the second shows "LIST OF FIGURES" on left and right sides, and the third page shows "List of Figures" on the bind side of the page (as wanted). I don't understand why `markboth` functions for one of the pages but not both. Can anyone help?

[image: Wrong header on the second page of the list of figures]
[image: Correct header on the third page of the list of figures]

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,openright]{report}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{{\chaptername}\ \thechapter.\ #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection.\ #1}}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\rightmark}
\fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\thepage}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
\fancyhead{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\thepage}}

\begin{document}

\clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\tableofcontents
\markboth{Contents}{}

\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}
\markboth{List of Figures}{}

\listoftables
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listtablename}
\markboth{List of Tables}{}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your \markboth command are way to late: You are issuing them at the end of the lists. Beside this: Your example can't be compiled due to the `\include` commands and so is rather useless.

Comment: Sorry for the include commands... I tried putting the `markboth` before the `addcontentsline`, or before the `listoffigures`, using or not using a `cleardoublepage` before that and nothing seems to work.

Comment: I suggest a better class. The `scrreprt` with the option `toc=listof` will do what you want. If you don't want to change check the command `\nouppercase` in the doc of fancyhdr.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `report` class issues

```
\@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}{\Make\listfigurename}
```

which is the main cause for your problem. You should issue `\addcontentsline` earlier, anyway. An approach is to modify `\listoffigures` and `\listoftables` to do the desired thing.

I recommend also to use `emptypage` so as to avoid having to do somersaults with `\thispagestyle{empty}`. Note also the setting of `\headheight`, which is necessary; `fancyhdr` tells you in the log file if you have to set it and also to what value.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,openright]{report}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\setlength{\headheight}{14.5pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{{\chaptername}\ \thechapter.\ #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection.\ #1}}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\rightmark}
\fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\thepage}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
\fancyhead{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\thepage}}

\makeatletter
%% patch \listoffigures not to issue \@mkboth but \markboth
%% and to issue \addcontentsline
\patchcmd{\listoffigures}
  {\@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}{\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}}
  {\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}\markboth{\listfigurename}{}}
  {}{}
\patchcmd{\listoftables}
  {\@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\listtablename}{\MakeUppercase\listtablename}}
  {\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listtablename}\markboth{\listtablename}{}}
  {}{}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}
\tableofcontents
\markboth{Contents}{}

\listoffigures

\listoftables

\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter{X}

% create a bunch of items to fill pages in the lists of tables and figures
\def\z{
  \begin{figure}[htp]
  \caption{A}
  \end{figure}
  zz
  \begin{table}[htp]
  \caption{B}
  \end{table}
  zz
}
\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\clearpage
\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\clearpage
\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\clearpage
\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\z

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How can I get smallcaps for "List of Figures" in the header?

Comment: @Damitr Use `\textsc{\leftmark}` and `\textsc{\rightmark}` in the setup for `fancyhdr`.

Comment: I have used `\fancyhead[LO]{\textsc{\smaller{\rightmark}}}` and 
`\fancyhead[RE]{\textsc{\smaller{\leftmark}}}` this gives correct formatting for chapter and chapter*, but for LoF and LoT, it is not making any difference. In the code posted above I have used `{\@mkboth{\textsc\listfigurename}{\textsc\listfigurename}}` 
 but it is still not changing the LoF header, which is coming out as uppercase.

Comment: @Damitr Sorry, but a fresh question with all the details is needed.